# xargs: zcat: terminated by signal 13

Tags: grep, xargs

I have used a script like below

zgrep -i xxxx FileA|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2|xargs -0 -I string zcat FileB| requestID="RequestID=" stringone=$requestID$string grep stringone FileB

Before the point of `xargs` being used my o/p is

```
01982893213982312 - RID 1
32103213213213213 - RID 2
32103213213213343 - RID 3
32103213213251261 - RID 4
```

For every RID present here, there is a corresponding line in File B. I am planning to do like the below after the:

```
zgrep -i xxxx FileA | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" | uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 | xargs|
{grep RID1 in file B, grep RID2 in file B,grep RID3 in file B, grep RID4 in file B}
```

Now if I do this I am getting an error 
xargs: zcat: terminated by signal 13

Please help me guys

Comment: the error means broken pipe/end of pipe, just go backwards by removing 1 pipe at a time and see where your results fail to meet your expectations, that's where you probably need to hunt for the pipe ending